# Ruby on Rails: How to customize validation error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a following code:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

Error message produced is "Name can't be blank"
Instead of using the actual attribute name (in this case "name") I want to 
display message as "Registration name can't be blank".
How do I overwrite the default message on the validations? I tried appending :message
but it didn't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In en.yml file define custom keys as:

```
activerecord: 
  attributes:
    model_name:
      attribute_name1: key1
      attribute_name2: key2
                 ......
```

This key will be used automatically when errors are generated.

Reference: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models
(5.1 Translations for Active Record Models)

Comment: Never heard about that. Wow, learned something new - nice answer! :)

Comment: @ream88 - second that. very nice answer indeed, will definitely use this. I had previously used a gem, more than a few months back, for custom error messages. The gem is hosted at https://github.com/nwise/custom_error_message.

Comment: To future readers, in case it's not clear, the `en.yml` file lives in `config/locales`.

Comment: sir can show your code? I got a error message say "can not load translations en.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not"

Answer (score 7):

This will do the trick:

```
validates :name, presence: { message: "Registration name can't be blank" }
```

or the old hash rocket syntax version:

```
validates :name, :presence => { :message => "Registration name can't be blank" }
```

Comment: But I still see the comment as "Name Registration name can't be blank" I want to get rid of the word "Name" from the message...

Comment: But this problem is related to your view.

Comment: You have definitely some code like: `<% model.errors.each do |name, error| %> <%= name %><%= error %> <% end %>`. The `<%= name %>` is were the first `name` come from.

Comment: @MarioUher No, @user_1357 is actually right, when you override the default message with `message` symbol the name of the column persists at the beginning. To eliminate this issue, you have to use `model.errors[:name].each` specifying which specific column you want the errors for. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Its a little late now (after about 35 days) to answer this. So, sorry for this. But just wanted to share that I had used a gem, more than a few months back, for custom error messages.

This plugin allows you to omit the attribute name for specific messages. All you have to do is begin the message with a ‘^’ character.

I just checked it at 
https://github.com/nwise/custom_error_message 
& it has not been updated since march. So, i probably used it at the right time.

ps : Your answer for defining the custom keys in the yml file is more appropriate though.